# Catching whole tag in RTF

Tags: php, regex

I have a system which handles document workflow in rtf. It works great with standard Rtf. And i know the regex able to handle it in word 2003. I wish to be able to handle word 2007.

My tags looks like this : [[FooBuzz]].

Many programs like wordpad, keep [[FooBuzz]] in plain text. Word 2003 explode the [[ from the tag.
Word 2007 is even worst he explode too at each caps. So Foo  Buzz.

My sample data :

```
{ toto}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 [[}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Foo}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Buzz}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 ]]} {toto}
```

I need 2 things. First the regex as to match the rtf  reprensation of [[FooBuzz]]

example :
    {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 [[}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Foo}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Buzz}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 ]]}

Second i want to select the name of the tag. Here FooBuzz. I have to use php function preg_match_all.

So this is a test result with doublinc my test datas :

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 [[}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Foo}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Buzz}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 ]]}
            [1] => {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 [[}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Foo}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Buzz}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 ]]}
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 [[}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Foo}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Buzz}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 ]]}
        [1] => {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 [[}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Foo}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2708730 Buzz}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid5517131 ]]}
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Foo
        [1] => Foo
    )
```

)

As you see, it generates tabs as needed. Key 1 is a bug i will handle later. Key 2 as results, only if [[FooBuzz]] is not exploded. Key 3, as results working with word 2003.

So Foo  and Buzz may be in differents array, that's good enough for me, as long it is consitent.

Example :

```
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Foo

    )
 [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Buzz

    )
```

OR

```
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => FooBuzz

    )
```

are accepted answers.

My regex and his explanations :

I received help on stackoverflow to build it :

```
/(\[\[([^\[\]]*?)\]\]|{[^{]*?\[\[.*?(?<=\[\[).+?\b(?<!\\)(\w+)\b(?=.+?\]\]).*?\]\].*?})/
```

In a more meaninful way :

```
/(        Begenning of the OR clause
 \[\[([^\[\]]*?)\]\]   Regex used to catch [FooBuzz] in plain text.
 |   Or statement.
 {[^{]*?\[\[.*?(?<=\[\[).+?  Part able to catch  the Rtf translation of [[
   \b(?<!\\)(\w+)\b     This part have a negative look behind. It match rtf metadata (ex \toto123. And i selects Foo
 (?=.+?\]\]).*?\]\].*?} Match the RTF translations of ]]
 )/ End of or statement.
```

Note : there is a lot of non greedy character (?), this way the regex select only the tag and his metadata if needed. (replace in plain text).

This is legacy code, i can't decide to abandon the plain text way. Perfomance don't matters, it runs in a batch.

How would you catch FooBuzz ?

Tests sites :

http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php display the ouput of preg_match_all.

http://rubular.com/r/5fm7afU5vG  Funnier to use and you can edit permalinks. As you see matches are displayed the same way than my target function.

In a nutshell :

```
I want to match all the RTF reprsentation of [[FooBuzz]] with match 1.
I want either match x => FooBuzz or match x => Foo match x + 1 => Buzz, if consistent.
```

You are free to add another Or. Otherwise i think the part to edit is : 
    \b(?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
/{[^{]*\[{2}.*?\b(\w+)}.*?(?:\b(\w+)}.*?)?\]{2}[^}]*}/
                   ↑             ↑
                  Foo          Buzz
```

#### PHP Code:

```
$pattern = '/{[^{]*\[{2}.*?\b(\w+)}.*?(?:\b(\w+)}.*?)?\]{2}[^}]*}/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

Test this code **[here](http://ideone.com/seMya)**.